# Hint to prove this $|A/(A\cap B)|\le|G/ B|$

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$. I need hint to show that $|A/(A\cap B)|\le|G/ B|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a system of representatives $a_i\in A$ such that $a_i(A\cap B)\ne a_j(A\cap B)$ for $i\ne j$. Show that also $a_iB\ne a_j B$.

Answer (score 0):

from the 'second isomorphism theorem'
$$
|A/A\cap B| = |AB/B| \le |G/B|
$$

Comment: It is not given that $B$ is normal. Therefore I'm not sure whether [second isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem) theorem holds.

Comment: sorry, yes of course...